# what url should I authorize to use R docker image behind a firewall?

Tags: r, docker, rstudio, firewall

We have a server and we want to use [rocker/tidyverse](https://rocker-project.org/images/) docker images for R, that is behind a company firewall. I want to make a firewall exception for specific URL/domains.
e.g.

```
1] cloud.r-project.org
2] ghcr.io
3] github.com
4] rocker-project.org
```

I want to pull docker image from rocker/tidyverse for R, for that which URL's should I ask to be listed in the exception rules for the firewall?